# What is the meaning of reserved bits and opcode -1 in WebSockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, web, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am new to nodejs and getting an error in the browser console.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://site.com/socket.io/1/websocket/MO2ub3-qOMOx5ADBh86i' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

what is the meaning of reserved bits?

what is meant by opcode -1 in the web sockets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'opcode -1' mean in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915732/what-does-opcode-1-mean-in-chrome)