# What does 'opcode -1' mean in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome browser and I'm trying to create a WebSocket connection (using javascript) but sometimes I get an error. When I'm looking in Developer Tools for the WS connection, I see OPCODE -1. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSocket OPCODEs describe how to interpret the frame. The OPCODES are formally between 0-10, OPCODE -1 says "not frame that can be used":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Exchanging_Data_Frames

https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-09.html#rfc.section.11.14

Comment: And what does `not frame that can be used` mean?

Comment: It could be lots of things. In general terms it means the frame cannot be decoded or is corrupted. As a reference, in the [Chromium implementation](https://github.com/Samsung/ChromiumGStreamerBackend/blob/820d17430deb0ba8ccef63d00d81a374f8239c4b/net/websockets/websocket_channel.cc) during the reading of the frame ([at line 412](https://github.com/Samsung/ChromiumGStreamerBackend/blob/820d17430deb0ba8ccef63d00d81a374f8239c4b/net/websockets/websocket_channel.cc#L412)) you will see a call to `WebSocketFrameHeader::IsKnownDataOpCode(op_code)` with the FATAL message text listed there.